# How can I place n circles randomly inside a rectangle without overlapping?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

Suppose I have **n** circles of radius **r**. I want to place them randomly inside a rectangle of size **A**x**A**.

It is guaranteed that they fit. One can suppose that the sum of the area of all circles is about 60% of the area of the rectangle.

I can try it by doing a backtracking, trying to place, going back, etc., but there should be a better way to do it.

Comment: Another way to phrase the problem might be "how can I choose a random point that is at least **r** distance away from any of the points in an existing set"?  (not that I know of any technique better than the one you suggested)

Comment: One possibility could be to generate random points inside the rectangle without further constraints, and then move the points/centres iteratively (by little steps) such that avoiding overlapping. If two points are too near one from each other, each point can bring pressure to the other, to make it goint away a little bit. The higher the pressure, the higher the move. Not so easy technically, especially taking into account the rectangle constraint. No real assurance it will converge.

Comment: @Damien That most certainly won't be uniform.

Comment: I would say that in the naïve approach the number of the test-for-intersection to perform is _O(n^2)_ and so basically you are looking for a faster way to do it, aren't you?

Comment: Use some dense packing of n circles of equal radii in the rectangle. Then place a circle of radius r in each randomly.

Comment: @orlp I agree. But I understand that the goal is not to have a uniform distribution of the circles. To be confirmed by OP what they really want.

Comment: @YvesDaoust This is a quite efficient approach, rather easy to implement. The advantage/drawback (?) is that the distribution will be rather uniform, for example with very few circles touching themselves. OP might detail what they intend by *randomly*.

Comment: @YvesDaoust's solution can even be simplified to making a grid of n squares (so having side lengths A/sqrt(n)) inside the rectangle, instead of a dense packing of n circles.

Comment: @Damien: with 40% of free space, the distribution *must* be somewhat uniform. Square packing already leaves 20%. For small n, dense packing is as difficult as the initial problem.

Comment: After having found a legal placement (no overlaps), you can move the individual circles as long as they don't hit others. The motion allowance can be found from the distance map of the centers. But you'll need a dynamic Voronoi implementation, something not so glamorous.

Comment: The problem is hard regardless, because you might be given an input where the n circles barely fit at all, or fit in exactly one way. In other words, this problem reduces to the circle packing problem. So in the worst case I don't believe an efficient algorithm is known. For example, if I give you `n = 15, r = 1 and A = 4 + sqrt(2) + sqrt(6)` you must be able to produce this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ee/15_circles_in_a_square.svg/512px-15_circles_in_a_square.svg.png

Comment: @Damien It isn't clear what "uniform" means in this context. How do you define measure in the space of sets of non-overlapping circles?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I am not the one who introduces "uniform" in the discussion. In my opinion, it doesn't mean to be understood in a strict probabilistic sense. More about a kind of homogeneity  of a given solution.

Comment: @orlp Isn't that [76%](https://tio.run/##bYzNCsIwEITveYq9SJsoiFWLCB76JCGExATy53YvIj57TAU99TIzMN9MeZLL6XgpWKvFHCEqcuBjyUgwP5B2UDxjCW5wODNcjE1NT7D91v3Af2nkjCk0SmYrVQhSe9TBzA1OINpLExRi@DPkjESjSaV7MI2alrKgT9Tb7rX2tIfV7XXz7nitHw)? OP said "about 60%".

Comment: with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to generate random points inside the rectangle without further constraints, and then move the points/centres iteratively (by little steps) such that avoiding overlapping. If two points are too near one from each other, each point can bring pressure to the other, to make it going away a little bit. The higher the pressure, the higher the move.

This process was implemented in C++. In the following simple code, to facilitate implementation, points and vectors are represented par `std::complex` type.

Note that I used `srand`and `rand` for test purpose. You may used better random algorithms, depending on your constraints.

According to the tests that I have performed, convergence seems guaranteed for a density of 60%.  I also made some tests with a density of 70%: sometimes convergence, sometimes not.

Complexity is `O(n^2 n_iter)`, where `n`is the number of circles and `n_iter`the number of iterations.
`n_iter`is generally between 100 and 300, for a density of 60%. It could be decreased with relaxing the convergence criteria.

It could be seems high complexity, compared to other proposals in comments. In practice, for `n = 15`, the work is performed in less than 30ms on my PC. Huge time or fast enough, depending on the context. I have included a figure to illustrate the algorithm.

[image: circles]

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
#include <tuple>
#include <ios>
#include <iomanip>

using dcomplex = std::complex<double>;

void print (const std::vector<dcomplex>& centers) {
    std::cout << std::setprecision (9);
    std::cout << "\ncenters:\n";
    for (auto& z: centers) {
        std::cout << real(z) << ", " << imag(z) << "\n";
    }
}

std::tuple<bool, int, double> process (double A, double R, std::vector<dcomplex>& centers, int n_iter_max = 100) {
    bool check = true;
    int n = centers.size();
    std::vector<dcomplex> moves (n, 0.0);
    double acceleration = 1.0001;        // to accelerate the convergence, if density not too large
                                        // could be made dependent of the iteration index
    double dmin;
    
    auto limit = [&] (dcomplex& z) {
        double zx = real(z);
        double zi = imag(z);
        if (zx < R) zx = R;
        if (zx > A-R) zx = A-R;
        if (zi < R) zi = R;
        if (zi > A-R) zi = A-R;
        return dcomplex(zx, zi);
    };
    int iter;
    for (iter = 0; iter < n_iter_max; ++iter) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) moves[i] = 0.0;
        dmin = A;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < n; ++j) {
                auto vect = centers[i] - centers[j];
                double dist = std::abs(vect);
                if (dist < dmin) dmin = dist;
                double x = std::max (0.0, 2*R*acceleration - dist) / 2.0;
                double coef = x / (dist + R/10000);
                moves[i] += coef * vect;
                moves[j] -= coef * vect;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "iteration " << iter << "  dmin = " << dmin << "\n";
        if (dmin/R >= 2.0 - 1.0e-6) break;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            centers[i] += moves[i];
            centers[i] = limit (centers[i]);
        }
    } 

    dmin = A;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; ++j) {
            auto vect = centers[i] - centers[j];
            double dist = std::abs(vect);
            if (dist < dmin) dmin = dist;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Final: dmin/R = " << dmin/R << "\n";
        
    check = dmin/R >= 2.0 - 1.0e-6;
    return {check, iter, dmin};
}

int main() {
    int n = 15;              // number of circles
    double R = 1.0;         // ray of each circle
    double density = 0.6;   // area of all circles over total area A*A
    double A;               // side of the square
    int n_iter = 1000;
    
    A = sqrt (n*M_PI*R*R/density);
    std::cout << "number of circles = " << n << "\n";
    std::cout << "density = " << density << "\n";
    std::cout << "A = " << A << std::endl;
    
    std::vector<dcomplex> centers (n);
    
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        double x = R + (A - 2*R) * (double) std::rand()/RAND_MAX;
        double y = R + (A - 2*R) * (double) std::rand()/RAND_MAX;
        centers[i] = {x, y};
    }
        
    auto [check, n_iter_eff, dmin] = process (A, R, centers, n_iter);
    std::cout << "check = " << check << "\n";
    std::cout << "Relative min distance = " << std::setprecision (9) << dmin/R << "\n";
    std::cout << "nb iterations = " << n_iter_eff << "\n";
    print (centers);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After some trials and a high number of iterations, I was able to get a `n = 15` solution with a density of 74.8%. Not as good as Wikipedia 76.2% solution, but not ridiculous taking into account the simplicity (naivity?) of the algorithm.

Comment: "wikipedia" what page, please? is it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square?

Comment: @WillNess the page mentioned by orlp in a comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ee/15_circles_in_a_square.svg/512px-15_circles_in_a_square.svg.png

Comment: thanks. and where does the 76.2% come from? how do you know the radius of those circles? the image indeed appears on the page I linked to. the table there specifies "0.243..." as "number density" for n=15 case. this would seem to indicate 75.6% (?) if so, your present solution is even better than you state. :)

Comment: ah, I see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70662157/how-can-i-place-n-circles-randomly-inside-a-rectangle-without-overlapping#comment124984812_70662157) above, now. it gives the figure. strange that the table is different (or I'm misinterpreting it...)

Comment: @Willness Please note that basically I didn't try to solve a packing problem, but a random generation problem. Sphere packing tries to optimize the density. Up to symmetries, the optimum solution, sphere packing, corresponds to one arrangement only. No randomness. No balloon throwing! Increasing the density was a way to test the algorithm.

Comment: looking e.g. at [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square#/media/File:7_circles_in_a_square.svg) this doesn't seem necessarily to be the case (one circle is loose) though the title does say "the densest packing". :) re your comment, before optimizing the density we need to place them, and you seem to have solved that! the smaller the square the closer you will be to the dense(est) packing -- though of course it seems likely your algo can fail when the bounds become a bit tight. but the question was about placement, not packing, anyway, so all is well.

Comment: in engineering, a non-perfect, good-enough solution, is good enough. :)